# Delphi XE, TListBox and onclick-slide event?

Tags: android, delphi, delphi-xe6

I'm trying to use the TListBox item in an android app.

Which is the best way to create something like the iPhone's settings menu? I have my list box, and I want to create the "slide effect" (I don't know how to explain it, I hope that you understood this) if one of the item's is pressed similar to the iOS' one.

Thanks!

Comment: I wanted to avoid spamming.. However, if this is your suggestion, I'm going to edit this question immediately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Under the Samples provided with Delphi XE4-6, there is a project called TabSliding, and another called Settings Project. Both should provide you with the details you need for both iOS and Android.